# Stop PhpStorm file watchers running recursively (with Autoprefixer)

Tags: css, phpstorm

I've a PhpStorm file watcher running autoprefixer. However the file watcher runs recursively. I think this is because it generates a new css file which the file watcher then runs on.

Is there a way to force them to run only once?

I think I need a scope of Project files because I am not directly editing the css file, instead I have a SCSS file that creates a CSS file which should then be auto prefixed. My settings are shown below.

[image]

Comment: You mean that it runs on already minified file (*.min.js) as well? And you want to prevent this?

Comment: @LazyOne, yes it runs on the file that has just been generated by the file watcher so I'll get: start file.css generates -> file.min.css generates -> file.min.css.min.css -> file.min.css.min.css.min.css etc...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to:

- **create custom scope** (`Settings | Scopes` .. or by clicking on corresponding "..." button in File Watcher);
- [optionally] include desired files (e.g. `*.css`) -- not really required as "File Type" field of File Watcher already covers it
- **exclude already modified files (`*.min.css`)**

Now use that scope in your File Watcher instead of default "Project Files"

Answer (score 0):

Excluding directories from the **Scope** using a custom scope also works. This example is from a Symfony2 project.

[image: Excluding 'web' directory using a custom scope]