# PhpStorm: how to add watcher on 1 JS file only and not on ALL JS files?

Tags: phpstorm

1) How to add a watcher on 1 file ONLY ?

The goal is to put a obfuscator on 1 JS file only (the `main.js`) : I was unable to do that: obfuscation is applied to ANY JS file I do modify.

2) How to avoid infinite recurrent rules ?
I have 2 watchers right now:

- minification on JS files
- obfuscation on JS files

Problem is: PhpStorm creates infinite `.min.obf.min.obf...js` : it looks it applies these 2 rules in endless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Scope` field to limit the watched files: create [custom Scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/scope.html) that will include only desired file(s) and/or folders and use it there in File Watcher.

Scope can accept both "include" and "exclude" patterns at the same time so it's very flexible in filtering the files.

---

The same approach for your second issue -- use scope to not to process already processed files.

For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24938053/783119

---

The alternative to having 2 separate File Watchers is creating some batch/shell script that will do that minification + obfuscation and use it as a program in File Watcher.

Another option -- use build tools (Grunt/Gulp or alike) and call appropriate task there.